# system returned with code 256

Tags: errors

From this morning I'm not able to compile even the most simple codes. I don't know why these errors are produced

```
    \documentclass[preview, border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsmath,esint}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{braket}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    W_{12} = \int_1^2
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

and I get:

```
    [1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
    (./formula.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
    cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
    pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file esint10.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
        ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
        system returned with code 256
        convert: unable to open image `formula.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2761.
        convert: no images defined `formula.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
        system returned with code 256


Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!
```

Comment: Presuming you have shell escape for conversion to later be successful the error shown is pointing at the esint (computer modern font) package so first try to run tlmgr commands to update font mapping (it may be easier using tlmgr --gui) if the problem is not cleared by that consider using tlmgr to unload esint package and reload it may have had a previous hiccup that a refresh could clear

Comment: correct it was the esint package I don't why I've included it

Comment: OK is it cleared with esint active in your main file? If so was it a map update or did you need to unload/reload ?

Comment: I'm not using that package anymore

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.